# Spacing messed up

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

What is up with my spacing here? When the labels contain text the spacing is fine but then they are empty they have white space between each label. Why is extra space being added when the labels contain empty text?

With text in labels (what I want it to look like):
[image]

With no text in labels (how I do not want it to look like):
[image]

***On the C# code behind side:***

```
        // On page load
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string ID = i.ToString();
            PopulateLastNameLabel(ID);
        }


        protected void PopulateLastNameLabel(string ID)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Width = 70;
            lbl.Height = 20;
            lbl.Text = "";
            lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lbl.ID = "lastname_" + ID;
            pnlLastNameLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
```

***On the ASP.NET side:***

```
<asp:Table ID="tblDisplayTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrizeNumberLabel" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrizeDropDownList" runat="server" Width="130px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNickNameLabel" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrizeNicknameTextBox" runat="server" Width="125px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFirstNameLabel" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlLastNameLabel" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailAddressLabel" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddButton" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

Comment: Use &nbsp; either in the code behind or in the html to keep the whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you question correctly, you need the following css (remove height from code behind).

The problem each control is in own table cell, so they won't horizontal align properly. So you need to set height explicitly for each control.

```
<style type="text/css">
    td div { margin-right: 5px; }
    td div input {border: 1px solid #828282; height: 21px; }
    td div span { height: 25px; line-height: 25px; }
</style>

<asp:Table ID="tblDisplayTable" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrizeNumberLabel" runat="server" Width="80px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrizeDropDownList" runat="server" Width="130px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlNickNameLabel" runat="server" Width="70px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrizeNicknameTextBox" runat="server" Width="125px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFirstNameLabel" runat="server" Width="70px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlLastNameLabel" runat="server" Width="70px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailAddressLabel" runat="server" Width="140px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddButton" runat="server" Width="40px">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string ID = i.ToString();
        TextBoxLabel(ID);
        PopulatePrizeNicknameLabel(ID);
        PopulateFirstNameLabel(ID);
        PopulateLastNameLabel(ID);
    }
}

protected void TextBoxLabel(string ID)
{
    TextBox lbl = new TextBox();
    lbl.Width = 65;
    lbl.Text = "";
    lbl.ID = "TextBox_" + ID;
    lbl.Text = ID;
    pnlNickNameLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
}

protected void PopulatePrizeNicknameLabel(string ID)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Width = 125;
    lbl.Text = "";
    lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lbl.ID = "PrizeNickname_" + ID;
    lbl.Text = ID;
    pnlPrizeNicknameTextBox.Controls.Add(lbl);
}

protected void PopulateLastNameLabel(string ID)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Width = 70;
    lbl.Text = "";
    lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lbl.ID = "lastname_" + ID;
    lbl.Text = ID;
    pnlLastNameLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
}

protected void PopulateFirstNameLabel(string ID)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Width = 70;
    lbl.Text = "";
    lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    lbl.ID = "firstname_" + ID;
    lbl.Text = ID;
    pnlFirstNameLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

[image]

I prefer creating controls one row at a time instead of one column at a time, but that is not OP.